# How can I identify $U'$ with $U$ by the map $U' \rightarrow U$ given by $(u,0) \mapsto u$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, direct-sum

I have to show this proposition:

Let $U$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $V=U \oplus W $. Then $V$ has subspaces $U'$ and $W'$ such that we can identify $U'$ with $U$, $W'$ with $W$ and such that $V$ is the internal direct sum if $U'$ and $W'$.

If I define $U'=\{(u,0) | u \in U\}$ and $ W' = \{(0,w) | w \in W \}$ and claim that these satisfy the things claimed in the proposition.

How can I identify $U'$ with $U$ by the map $U' \rightarrow U$ given by $(u,0) \mapsto u$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking, but it seems like you question is something like "what does the question mean when it says *identify $U'$ with $U$*?".  I suspect that the answer to this question is that "identifying $U'$ with $U$" simply means showing that the two vector spaces are isomorphic, "in a natural way".

So, by defining the map $\phi:U' \to U$ by $\phi(u,0) = u$, you have given an example of a "natural" isomorphism between the spaces $U'$ and $U$.  Thus, you have shown that $U'$ and $U$ are naturally isomorphic.  That is, you have "identified" $U'$ with $U$.

The notion of "natural isomorphism" is made rigorous with category, but for the purposes of the question asked the fact that $\phi$ is a "sufficiently nice" map (admittedly a subjective criterion) is enough to say that we have indeed identified the two spaces as being "the same".

Comment: Thank you! I understand what "identified" does mean now. But can you elaborate the last bit of your comment (ϕ is a "sufficiently nice" map (admittedly a subjective criterion) is enough to say that we have indeed identified the two spaces as being "the same"))?

Comment: @user719856 Here's a slightly more rigorous explanation.  The reason that $\phi$ is "sufficiently nice" is that we were able to define the map using only the information that $U$ is a vector space and did not need to make any arbitrary choices.  Note, for instance, that at no point did the construction of the map require that we select a basis of $U$.